# How to extract numbers or digits using OCR in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

I try to extract numbers using OCR.

The development environment is run by pycharm (Python version 3).

My problem is how to extract numbers using OCR.

The image looks like this:

[image: Input image]

In the picture above I want to get the following numeric text:

```
1 2   3
4 5 6 7
8 9   0
```

How can I get the results I want?

Answer (score 0):

There a range of libraries to achieve this here is an example of one from:
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/
https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Example tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

# Simple image to string
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. I've done it that way but I don't get the output I want.

Comment: please can you update your question and show what this method did? and why its wrong? this will make it easier to help

Comment: CodeCupboard I'm really sorry, but do you get the output I want from my input?

Answer (score 0):

You can Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image then extract each number. After thresholding we get this

[image]

Now we iterate through the contours and extract/save each ROI

[image]

Now you can apply your desired OCR tool to read the text on each ROI

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c, num in zip(cnts, range(len(cnts))):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = 255 - thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(num), ROI)

cv2.imshow('thresh', 255 - thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But what I want is a whole array of numbers. (Like the output at my question.)
For example, like the input image above, 1, 2, {}, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, {}, 0.
What should I do?